# (coded) character sets - why mapping to code points in unicode?

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, character

As far as I understand a coded character set maps/assigns numbers (called code points) to an (abstract) character (eg. the german character ü to the code point 00FC in unicode).

This code point can be encoded (e.g. represented in byte patterns) in different ways:

UTF-8 (1 Byte), UTF-16 (2 Bytes) and UTF-32 (4 Bytes)

So the process is:

(abstract) characters ---> maps to code points (coded) character set --> encoding of code points to 1...n bytes

Why this intermediate stage of code points? Why are (abstract) characters not directly mapped to 1...n bytes?

(abstract) characters --> maps to 1...n bytes

This intermediate stage (assign numbers to characters) is also done in other (encoded) character sets. So there must be good reasons for it.

I want to understand why no direct mapping to bytes is done and if there are character sets which doesn't have this intermediate stage and directly maps to bytes.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Answer (score 1):

> Why are (abstract) characters not directly mapped to bytes?

To do that we would have to have one single byte encoding scheme that everyone agreed was best for every possible scenario.

We are a very long way off that being true. UTF-8, -16 and -32—not to mention all the other legacy encodings that are never going away—all have different strengths and are used for different purposes by different communities.

With multiple byte encodings unavoidably in play, you need a unified coded character set behind them, so that each encoding can be mapped back and forth to that character set. The alternative is that you have to have a combinatorial explosion of mapping tables between each possible pair of encodings.

(That's is what we had before Unicode. The tables were incomplete, lossy and inconsistent. It was not good times.)

Comment: I mean in general why is an (abstract) character not directly mapped to a byte sequence (1...n bytes). I.e. if I have an A (abstract character), which I maps to an code point 65 (0x41). Now I have to decide how my code point should be represented as byte sequence. I could mmap this code point to one byte (0100 0001) or to two bytes (0000 0000 0100 0001). So why this intermediate mapping to an integer? I could directly map to one or two bytes.

Comment: Again, you could, if you had god-like powers to go back a century and force everyone to agree on the same byte sequence for each possible character. In the absence of that ability, there are multiple possible byte encodings for each character, so you need to identify and order each character so that you can resolve the mappings between them. If the only way you have to refer to the upper-case latin ‘a’ character is to say “the character whose UTF-16LE byte representation is 0x41,0x00” you have not made things any easier for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why I need a number to identify each character? I could say "Capital Letter A" in ASCII or "Capital Letter A" in Unicode or "Capital Letter A" in Latin-1 to identify the character. 
I.e. if I know the "name" of my character and the underlying charset the character is identified as well. The number is just another way to identify the character in the charset or not? (e.g. 65 for capital letter A).
So why a number and not just a "name"?

Comment: Because there is no connection between a character's name and its binary representation. If all you knew is that ‘’ is called ‘BAMUM LETTER PHASE-D SHEE’ you would then need a mapping table that also tells you that ‘’ is f096a3bd in UTF-8 and d81adcfd in UTF-16 and 000168fd in UTF-32, as well as any other encodings that exist. And you would need the same table for every single character.

Comment: A single integer is much, much simpler to process than an arbitrary-length string like `"BAMUM LETTER PHASE-D SHEE"`, especially when you have a sequence of them. And having a defined integer range allows new characters to be added at previously undefined numbers without requiring all existing software to be updated to handle it.

Comment: I try to summarize my understanding. An character is mapped to an integer like A -> 65. Without this intermediate stage (map character to integer) I would need large tables for every encoding scheme which assigns a bit pattern for every encoding to the character. For example to represent five characters A,B,C,D,E in UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 I would need a table with 15 mappings.But with the intermediate mapping to integers I need only 5 mappings which assigns a number to the character und 3 general mappings for UTF-8,-16, -32 which are based on the binary representation of the underlying integer.

Comment: But what if I have only one single encoding scheme like in ASCII? 
In this case I could directly assign an bit pattern to an character. 
Because I have only one encoding in ASCII.
So for unicode such an intermediate stage (map character to integer and represent this integer as byte pattern) 
is useful because I use the binary representation of the number in the different encodings. But why such an intermediate stage for ASCII?

Answer (score 0):

This is simply to separate the different entities - code points (numbers) and their representation. It should also be taken into account that the majority of the code points in Unicode is reserved, that is, they do not yet have characters associated with them.